# Unity InputField save text error nullreference

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, input-field

**Solution**
The issue is the difference between Text Mesh Pro InputField and the native InputField.  I was using TMP which seems to be different when referencing it. I reverted to native Inputfield and it worked immediately.

**Original Error**
I am trying to save the text from an inputfield into a variable to use across scenes.  Currently I cant even get it to save the text alone as I get a null-reference.  Ive tried multiple solutions and nothing is working.  Using the exact same examples from YouTube and other online sources.

I have also tried using PlayerPrefs.SetString / GetString with no real luck.

Current Setup is as follows.

1. Script below collects and saves the text to a public variable. 
   Script is attached to empty GameObject
2. InputText is associated to the text part of the inputField When
   pressing Start I get the null reference.
3. Start button simply calls the "SaveAddress()" Function

**Error Message**

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SaveTipBotAddress.SaveAddress () (at Assets/Scripts/SaveTipBotAddress.cs:25)
```

**Text Scripts**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveTipBotAddress : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string ilpAddress;
    public GameObject inputText;

    public void SaveAddress()

    {

        ilpAddress = inputText.GetComponent<Text>().text;
    }

}
```

[image: InputField Text referenced in Script]

[image: Start Button Calls SaveAddress Script]

Comment: Your `inputText` field is set to `ILP_TextField` but you did not show that object.

Comment: You probably referenced the wrong object - not the one which the `Text` component attached but the one with the text area component. In that case `GetComponent` doesn't find the `Text` and returns `null`. To be sure next time you can use `GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true)` Instead or have a look at [Ebleme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58141660/7111561)

Comment: It shows in the images. ILP_TextField is the actual text inside the InputField so knowing its referenced should be sufficient.  however that being said it was a TMP InputField issue.  Refer to edit on original Q and answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I see that ILP_TextField is a Text object inside an InputField. In order to get text from an InputField you need to get a reference of that InputField after than you can get your text using `InputField.text` property.

On the Inspector you nedd to set assing the "Tex Area" object to Input Text Area field.

Your script will be like that:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveTipBotAddress : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string ilpAddress;
    //public GameObject inputText;

    public InputField inputTextArea;

    public void SaveAddress()    
    {
        ilpAddress = inputTextArea.text;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out the issue.  All answers were helpful but the main issue was I was using InputField - TextMeshPro.  Im not sure on the difference between calling fields in that and the native InputField but it worked right away when I used the native InputField.

Sorry and Thank you.